# Manifest or Theme/Style for a IWebBrowser2 control?

Tags: winapi, iwebbrowser2

The IWebBrowser2 control has password edit boxes which are squares.  This happened many years ago if you were on an XP machine, and you had a password edit field without a manifest file, you would get squares (no character found for the * they put in there with that font).  My application has a manifest file.  However I don't know how to give a manifest or set the theme or style of the control that is created.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify [DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753277(VS.85).aspx) in your implementation of IDocHostUIHandler.

Comment: I was actually doing this.  Upon further examination, it is applying the theme properly.  I set it to use the DOCUHOSTUIFLAG_NOTHEME and saw my buttons turn to boxes (win98 style).  However the password field is still squares (which works fine in the real browser).  Some password fields are not squares though.  So it is like the browser does not have all the fonts available.  I will continue to look at it.  Let me know if you have any other insight.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken.  IE has the boxes too, however no other browsers do.  I assumed it was a manifest, but it was completely just a bug with the web browser.  Your answer is correct for the way that I asked the question and does solve the manifest issue for anyone who has it.  Thanks again!